# UIAlertView not displaying complete message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I have the following function to display error messages to user. But it does not seem to show the complete message. It will display upto certain characters followed by ....

How can I make it show the entire message?

```
(void) showAlert:(NSString*)title forMessage:(NSString*) body
{
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:body delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

Comment: Approximately how long is the message you're trying to display?  `UIAlertView` has a limit as to how long the message can be, after that it's clipped.

Comment: its close to 100 chars or so.. I think AlertView clips it around 60.. is there any way to show more characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way.

When you present your alert, you can just implement this method:

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
alertView.frame = CGRectMake(alertView.frame.origin.x, alertView.frame.origin.y -50
                             ,alertView.frame.size.width, 300);
}
```

Adjust the height to fit your need.  It will look something like this:

[image]

If you need to move the button around, you can just add new lines (`\n`) to your message, and it will move the button down.

Comment: Seems to be mostly unnecessary in iOS 6. But I have noticed that there is some truncation, even with short titles, if the string ends in a space.

Comment: If I add a UITextField as a subview, the message will become and scrollable text and won't make the alert view taller, no matter how many \n I insert. What is this for?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by sudo rm -rf, UIAlertView has a limit.

You can try creating your own "alert" that doesn't clip by creating a view controller and showing it using `presentModalViewController:animated:`.