# Subclassing a UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios, scroll, subclass, uialertview

I'm desperately trying to find a way to make a custom UIAlertView that allows to display long texts and that would also allow to scroll the text as well. It seems to be possible since I've seen a few apps that do it (biteSms for instance) but I don't know how to do it.

Could someone help me please and tell me if any of you has managed to do it ?

Thanks for your help.

Miky Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the two answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548387/uialertview-not-displaying-complete-message/4548478#4548478).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks, I'll give it a try and tell you about it. Is that one scrolling ? I think I saw that page overnight but I wasn't sure it would meet my needs. I'll try it anyway. Thanks for the tip in the mean time. Have a nice day and all the best !

Comment: If you want scrolling, it would be better to go with my answer to that question: create your own view controller and present it using `presentModalViewController:animated:`.