# UIlocalNotification body

Tags: iphone, uialertview, uilocalnotification

How can make UILocal Notification if I need to show all body

```
 localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@", nil),
                        strMessage];
localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Happy_%@",strMessage] forKey:ToDoItemKey];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber+1;    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

This problem

[image]

Comment: Try this solution


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548387/uialertview-not-displaying-complete-message

Comment: @bpolat this will not work, as the alertView pictured above is shown on the lockscreen/homescreen

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: you can't. You may want to shorten the text, or display a full message when the user opens the app from this notification.
Note that clipping is not just depending on the number of characters, but also on the character width (if you are supporting multiple languages).